# How do I show that this topology on this linearly-ordered set is regular?

Tags: general-topology, vector-spaces

Given some linear ordered set $X$, we define a topology by the basis: all sets of the form $(a,b)$ or $(a,\infty)$ or $(-\infty,b)$, where $a,b \in X$.

I need to prove that this topology is regular, i.e. that for a closed set $H \in X$, and for $p \in X$ s.t. $p \notin H$ there exist two disjoint open sets in $X$, s.t. $p \in U$ and $ H \subset V$.

My intuition tells me that every closed set is a union of sets of the form $[b,\infty)\cup(-\infty,a]\cup[a,b]$. Is this correct? If so I think the proof is pretty straight forward, but I feel like I'm missing something. Where am I wrong?

Comment: Hm, if $a<b$, then $(a,b)\cup(a,\infty)\cup(-\infty,b)=X$, and $[b,\infty)\cup(-\infty,a]\cup[a,b]=X$ too. What do $(a,b)$ and $[a,b]$ mean to you when $a\ge b$?

Comment: What do you mean by  $(a,b)\cup (a,\infty)\cup (-\infty, b)$ being a basis?

Comment: Yes I knew I had a mistake. In the orginal definition $a \leq b$. I guess what I wrote doesn't make sense. Is it true to say that all closed sets are of the form $[b,\infty)\cup(-\infty,a]$?

Comment: I'll edit right now, my definition wasn't clear for the basis.

Comment: Closed sets can be quite arbitrary. But then again it suffices to show that whenever $x$ is in a set $U$ of the form $(a,b)$ or $(a,∞)$ or $(−∞,b)$, where $a,b∈X$, then there is a set $V$ of the form $(c,d)$ or $(c,∞)$ or $(−∞,d)$, where $c,d∈X$, such that $x\in V\subseteq \bar V\subseteq U$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $p\in X$ be a point and $H\subseteq X$ be a closed set such that $p\notin H$. Since $H^c$ is open and $p\in H^c$, there is a basic open set $V\subseteq X$ such that $p\in V\subseteq H^c$.

*Case I:* $V=(a,\infty)$ for some $a\in X$. If there is some $x\in X$ such that $a<x<p$, then $(-\infty,x)$ and $(x,\infty)$ are disjoint open sets containing $H$ and $p$, respectively. If, on the other hand, there is no such $x\in X$ (that is, $p$ is an immediate successor of $a$), then $(-\infty,p)$ and $(a,\infty)$ are disjoint open sets containing $H$ and $p$, respectively.

*Case II:* $V=(-\infty, b)$ for some $b\in X$. Completely analogous.

*Case III:* $V=(a,b)$ for some $a,b\in X$. Combine the previous two cases and take unions.